# Background color for listchars chars

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, color, listchars

I use the solution from this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/422/displaying-tabs-as-characters) to display tabs  with litlle ⸱ characters. It works but they appear on a lighter gray background than the dark gray background I am using.
It is quite distracting as unimportant information is highlighted.

Is there a way to avoid that ? What should I do ?

I am using vim with the beloved [solarized8](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8) theme. I have the same behavior on Gnome Terminal, Terminator and Alacritty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read `:help 'listchars'` (almost at the end).

Comment: And/or `:help hl-SpecialKey`.

Comment: Thanks @Matt and filbranden. From what I understand tabs are now highlighted as specified by the SpecialKey group. How do I make them higlighted as the NonText group for example ?

Comment: @cassepipe `:h 'hl'` (Vim only, not supported in Neovim).But, I think, it' more common to set it up the other way round (i.e. to change colorscheme / SpecialKey colors). I'm pretty sure there were many similar questions asked already.

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way is to put `hi SpecialKey ctermbg=NONE` in your `.vimrc` after calling in your favorite colorscheme.

Else you can read this gist and learn some true vim wizardry : https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f

Why SpecialKey ? The answer resides at the end of the `:help 'listchars'` section of the help pages.

Comment: FYI. Yet another trick [to patch colorscheme w/o patching file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26438/22797).